# How to check and change permissions of files and folders for web server in windows?

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, web-server, permissions, file-permissions

I have installed Apache server on Windows 7. When I try to access the server by its IP address I get in Chrome:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /
>   on this server.

In IE I get:

> The website declined to show this
>   webpage
>    HTTP 403      Most likely
>   causes:
>  •This website requires you to
>   log in.

I want to emphasize that I get another message if I type arbitrary IP. So, the server is working it just does not want to show me files.

I checked already ports (port 80 is opened, I think). And in my "httpd.conf" file I have "Listen 80".

At the moment I think that **the problem is in permissions to files and folders**. Can anybody tell me how can I check the permissions of files and folders, how can I change them (DOS analog of Linux's chmode), and which permission I need to set (so that people from outside can see my files but they cannot do something bad).

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be permissions-related, but in most cases, I'd say it's caused by not having a `index.html` file at your `DocumentRoot`, and not having `Options Indexes` enabled. (What is your `DocumentRoot`, anyhow?) From [Wikipedia](http://en.Wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403):

> [403] is returned by the Apache web server when directory listings have been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The command you want is cacls - run it in command prompt and check the options. You could right click the folder > properties, and change the permissions in here too.